# JAWS does not automatically read page even though it does when using the "Say All" command

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I'll try to keep it simple.
JAWS will read the page fine when I use the "Say All" command (Insert + Down arrow), but it does not read the whole page without that prompt.

Because it reads it well with the "Say All" command, I'm assuming that my HTML semantics is set up correctly.

So, is there a way to force JAWS to force read the page? Or is there a way to debug whatever issue JAWS is seeing?

Comment: If you think the issue isn't with your code then isn't this a product question, not a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with BSMP.  You don't have to test your website with the read all command.  Just make sure when you navigate with JAWS, it's doing the right thing.  Try some quick keys such as T to navigate to a table or H to a header.  Use Ins+F5 to see all your form fields to make sure they're labeled properly, Ins+F7 to see if your links have appropriate labels, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that document automatically reads is set to on. Do this by hitting insert+v then going to general options under virtualc cursor.